# Detect if WindowState is snapped

Tags: vb.net

So, there is a way to "Half" maximize things, (when you drag a form to the side of your screen it fills it up with half, and in Windows 10 you can fill a quarter of the screen.) how can we detect that?

```
If WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal Then My.Settings.Size = Size
```

That code runs when its half minimized/quarter. How can I detect the other "maximized" states?

Comment: you mean with a snap?

Comment: Those states are just normal states. Snap makes it easier to resize widowed to these sizes, but from the program's point of view, they are just a resize.

Comment: Yea i mean snap, I don't want that code to basically execute if its snapped.

Comment: Execute it when snapped. Otherwise you will confuse the user. "When I resize the window manually to 400 pixels, it works, but when I use snap to resize the window to 400 pixels, it doesn't work."

Comment: How???? Thats what im asking for? How.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you have to calculate this one.

```
If me.width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width / 2 And me.left = 0 Then
    'code
End If
```

shouldnt be that hard to create some checks for every possible option and then put it in a function that returns a Enum like

```
Enum snap As Integer
    isLeft
    isRigh
    isTop
    isBotton
    NoSnapDetected
End Enum
```

same goes the different direction - when you wanna set your window to that size/point

Comment: There should be a way to know it without calculations.

Comment: as @Raymond-Chen said it's just a simple resize, so i don't think they'll add any support for this :/