# Programmatically Detect If Form is Snapped

Tags: vb.net

I've been having problems trying to figure out how to detect if the form is snapped onto one side of the desktop. My recent [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26705871/detect-if-windowstate-is-snapped) from a couple months ago didn't solve my problem, and I was gone for a while, but I'm now back.

What the code below does is on `Form1_ResizeEnd` it saves the size of the form. I'm trying to prevent the size to save when the form is snapped onto one side of the desktop.

```
If WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal Then My.Settings.Size = Size
```

I've tried this code below (written by [Index](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4151552/index)), but it didn't work out for me.

```
If me.width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width / 2 And me.left = 0 Then
'code
End If
```

And also if possible how can I detect if its being snapped to a quarter of the screen like in Windows 10?

Comment: That other thread answered it pretty well. If there actually is a genuine problem with the answers you got there, you could express that problem there.

Comment: @HeyHeyJC I said that, that answer did not answer my question, because it didnt work.

Comment: In what way didn't the answers work? You said "There should be a way to know without calculations"... well, there isn't, sorry. Complain to Microsoft. Then you said "It doesn't work", which tells us nothing. I just tried the code posted as the answer: took me one minute and it worked perfectly, detecting a snap to the left side of the screen. I'll give you another answer here, and if you have a problem with it, explain what. (Also in general, no-one here is getting paid to help you, so being more polite, less curt, and more forthcoming will get you better responses.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no form events associated with snapping, so to decide whether the form was snapped you have to handle the "Resize" event, and calculate whether it was (probably) snapped or not. Here's code to look for left or right snapping, you can extend the principle for the other possible snaps:

```
Sub Form1_Resize(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
    If Not LeftRightSnapped() Then
        SaveScreenSize()
    Else
        Debug.Print("Don't save sizes")
    End If
End Sub

Function LeftRightSnapped() As Boolean
    Dim HalfScreenWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width / 2
    Return (Me.Width = HalfScreenWidth) And ((Me.Left = 0) Or (Me.Left = HalfScreenWidth))
End Function

Sub SaveScreenSize()
    Debug.Print("Save sizes here!")
End Sub
```